# Make Vue3 detect when a key is updated within a dictionary, which is in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

```
<tr v-for="(object,index) in watchingArr" :key="index">
   <span>{{ object.1 }}{{ object.2 }} {{ object.3 }}</span>
</tr>
```

I am aware that Vue3 can only detect changes in array when size changes, and only if the `deep` flag is set to true.

However, the deep flag cannot detect ***when a variables changes***.

I see that in Vue2 `Vue.set()` was a solution, but deprecated now in Vue3.

tl;dr

```
this.element[newKey] = newVal 
this.$store.dispatch('store/addElement',this.element) <--- Adds element to watchingArr
```

^ Works because we are adding a new element to the array

```
this.element[oldKey] = newVal
```

^ Does not work because we are only updating the value of the key within the array

By the way, I did check, it does update the actual array, I am sending references to the array and not copies.

SOLUTION:

This specific array was an array of Leaflet.js markers. Since my list was its own Vue3 Component, I attached a Vue3 function to the marker.

```
...
marker["customFunction"] = this.customFunction
...
},
customFunction(){
(change store variable 'updateList')
}
```

Then trigger the function on dragend

```
this.marker.on('dragend', function(event) {
event.target.customFunction
}
```

=================

On the list component, it would watch the store variable, and `this.forceUpdate()` to update the list

Comment: But `:key="index"` isn't updated. Consider adding a meaningful id as a key instead

Comment: The core functionality is based on Index. 

When a ```person``` is added, update the list. 

But I also want to update when say the ```name``` of the person is updated

Comment: WHat reactivity are you giving `watchingArr`? Can you show that portion of your codebase?

Comment: ```watchingArr``` is a variable within vuex store. 


```export default{
namespaced: true,
state: {
 watchingArr
}
```

Let me clarify the process.


New Element Created -> Dispatch new Element to VuexStore -> VuexStore pushes new Elment into ```watchingArr``` -> Vue3 list component watches ```watchingArr```->```v-for``` renders based on that watched arr

Comment: As said, this you need some id, proceed from the fact that v-for element is not updated until key is updated. If an element is identified by name, it should be :key="object.name", or some synthetic uid

Comment: If you key list items by index, Vue will not watch changes in anything other than each item's index. So as long as you keep the same number of items in the list, you can swap elephants with ants and then with monkeys three times per second, Vue won't re-render. If you want to understand why, consider reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76343552/1891677). And even if you add to the list, the initially rendered n items will not be updated, because the index doesn't change.

Comment: Apologies because it feels like I am missing something. If say I move to UUID, so the array becomes ```[UUID,marker]``` , and the key for the ```v-for``` becomes ```UUID``` , the ```UUID``` is only generated on a new marker. Even beyond all this, the core of the problem is still not being addressed. An array of objects, how to detect changes within an object. If every object has Lat/Lon, how to detect changes to the lat lon, do I just need 2 v-fors? or a ```ref``` for every objects lat/lon?